# Does interdiction technology exist in other universes other than Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, technology

In Star Wars Rebels, we see an Interdictor cruiser, which is capable of pulling other ships out of hyperspace. Since most other science fiction universes have hyperspace as a means of trans-galactic or inter-galactic travel, has anyone else developed this kind of technology other than the Empire? Just the name of the organization and the technology are needed. Only universes were hyperspace (existing under that name) exists will be accepted. No Warp speed nothing but simple hyperspace.

Comment: What kind of crazy talk am I spouting!?  Of *course* there's a [TVTropes page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoWarpingZone) for this!

Comment: this is relating to hyperspace, not warp

Comment: Did you read the page?  The title is not the content; it lists many examples in *Star Wars*.  Besides "hyperspace" is just what FTL is called in *Star Wars*; the same term might be used differently elsewhere, or the same phenomenon might have a different name.

Comment: I think my latest edit to it makes the question quite a bit clearer now

Comment: The question is asking for a list of works where this technology exists and list questions are off topic no matter how clear you phrase them.

Comment: then delete the question. If it is off-topic and closed, why not just delete it and be done?

Comment: Questions can only be deleted by the question asker providing there are no positive answers, diamond moderators at any time and 3 20k users providing the question is closed and has a score of -3 or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Star Trek Into Darkness (Kelvin Timeline)'s USS Vengeance was described has to have speed and weaponry to chase down and force other ships out of warp.

> The Vengeance's phaser armament was extremely powerful – a focused barrage could penetrate the defensive shields of a standard starship (even at warp velocities), breach the hull and damage critical systems, and thereby force the other ship from warp back into normal space.

(quoting from Memory Alpha, Star Trek canon info reference website)

EDIT: In EVE Online there are warp disruptors and warp scramblers.

> Warp Scramblers and Warp Disruptors aim to disrupt the warp drive of a locked target to try and prevent it from warping away. If a ships warp drive is disabled because of such modules or a warp disruption field, it is "scrambled", or "pointed".

Comment: to be accurate, that is warp speed, not hyperspace. On another note, however, that is a good place to start

Comment: Are we really going to quibble over what's hyperspace and what's warp space? :D

Comment: No, I was just pointing out the differences.

Answer (score 1):

[The Borderland of Sol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Borderland_of_Sol), a story in Larry Niven's *Known Space* series, concerns a plot to precipitate ships out of hyperspace using a controlled quantum black hole.